# Module which is not a top module

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Top modules were defined in this [article](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927879708825840?journalCode=lagb20). Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ an $R$-module, throughout for any submodule  $N$ of $M$, $V(N)$ denotes the set $\{P\in Spec(M)|N\subseteq P\}$, and
  $\mathcal{V}(M)$ denotes the set $\{V(N)|N \leq M\}$. Clearly, $V(0)=Spec(M)$, $V(M)=\emptyset$ and for any family of submodules $N_i$ of $M$, $\bigcap\limits_{i\in I}V(N_i)=V(\sum\limits_{i\in I}N_i)$. But $\mathcal{V}(E)$ is not closed under finite union in general.

I want to fined a module $M$ which is not top module since $V(N)\cup V(L)\neq V(E)$ where $N,~L,~E$ are submodules of $M$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The following theorem is useful for constructing examples:

> Theorem:1) A free $R$-module $F$ is top if and only if it is cyclic. 2) If $R$ is a perfect ring, then an $R$-module is top if and only if it is cyclic.

Example 1: The $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ is not top.

Example 2: It is rutin to check that the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_p$ is not a top module, where $p$ is a prime number(without usnig obove theorem).

By definition, a perfect ring is a type of ring in which all left modules have projective covers. Since every vector space is  projective, every field is perfect. Thus by above theorem a vector space $F$ over a field $K$ is top if and only $Dim_K(F)=1$.

Comment: Thank you. But I want an example in which the third condition is obvious not hold.

Comment: Cosider Example 1, and show that it is not top( first determine $Spec(\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z})$.